# How to generate embedded element for other site to consume?

Tags: django, web

If I put a link on a comment on Twitter, facebook and other place the website analyse the link and show a small preview of the link if possible. It could be a small player for a video or an image with a title, etc.

How does this work?
Is there a standard request made to the site to get an embed version of the page?

How can I do this on my site so the links shared by my users get the best visibility possible?

I am using Django and my content is recipes: an image with a title would make great embed.

Comment: This question is better suited for [so]. Hint: Google `oembed`.

Comment: Thanks, I will vote this the answer if you put it there.
Right, I don’t know why I didn’t think of Stack Overflow?